# why do i need to unplug and then plug my use mouse to activate it after restart?

Tags: windows, mouse

every time i restart my windows system i need to do that, otherwise system will say the driver is error, and my mouse can not move.
do anyone have solutions for this ?

Comment: You should tell us which windows OS, what mouse, and if you have installed any drivers for it.

Comment: windows vista and windows 7, they all have this problem, and my mouse is hyundai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to try:

- Download the mouse drivers directly from the mouse manufacturer and research compatibility with your OS
- Use a different USB port
- Unplug the mouse, manually remove the mouse in device manager, restart the computer, then plug the mouse back in. The drivers will reinstall automatically.
- Plug in a different mouse and see if that exhibits the same issues.

If none of the above work, it is probably a hardware problem with the mouse. In that case, it would probably be best to get a new mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the cmos battery out(from the mobo, obviously with the power off) leave out for about 5 mins.
Put the cmos battery back in, this should clear the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use USB3 ext cables on your mouse or kb or put them in a usb3 port? This is the problem I had using my NUC. There were no USB2 ports until I purchased the new lid that had USB2 ports built in and jumpers to access the onboard ports. I originally thought it was a voltage problem, the way the mouse kept dropping out. After reading many of the hundreds of people having this same problem, and trying these generic fixes that did not work, I read about that USB2 and USB3 ports are not really that compatible as far as keyboards and mice are concerned. The problems are popping up more now since many new computers are now coming sans USB2 ports dues to space concerns. My problems is fixed.